# Angular and Angular Dart (and Flutter)

Tags: angular, web, dart, flutter, angular-dart

I've been thinking about using Angular Dart, right now I'm using **Angular** and **TypeScript** and it's a *really good framework*, but I tried **Flutter** and I absolutely loved it, it was perfect, the widgets, the language, everything just just worked perfectly together. So I saw that I can use Angular with Dart, it had a great documentation, includes material design, so I started to look into it and I barely found anything about it, sure it has pub with all the packages, but most of them are for Flutter, I noticed I can only use choco with cmd in admin mode to run the webdev serve and some other flaws that didn't really like, and also the community seems dead. In december Flutter announced that they are working on **Hummingbird** (Flutter for the web) and they are going cross-platform, and I can't wait to see what they will come up with, and I want to start moving towards Flutter, but I have new projects, so I can't wait for Hummingbird right now, now I have to decide if we're going to use **Angular, or Angular Dart**. What are your opinions on this matter? What would you choose right now?

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO. I'd say if the main focus is to build a fancy web UI, then Angular TS is probably the better option because there are much more libraries available. If you rather build everything yourself, you can also go with Angular Dart. The main benefit for Angular Dart is IMHO that you can share most code between Flutter and Web except the UI presentation layer and platform-specific functionality like storage, authentication, sensors, and such stuff, ... If Hummingbird becomes reality, then you can just drop the Angular UI layer and run Flutter on the web directly.

Comment: You beat me to it @GünterZöchbauer =D. Just to add though, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask this type of thing. But for the record, I've used AngularDart for my web app and well.... it leaves somewhat to be desired. It doesn't seem to have the same overarching vision that flutter does as some things seem to be done an 'angular way' while others are done the 'dart way'. For a massive application it would probably be fine as you'd probably invest in building all your components from scratch, but for a relatively small one the overhead is significant.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ !

Comment: I'm sorta waiting for hummingbird to come out and if it delivers at all well on what it promises I'll be transitioning as much as possible over to it lol. But for now, you're probably best splitting your business logic from your UI code as that's a useful exercise anyways, and you could theoretically set up some sort of pipeline with dart2js to compile just your business logic to JS

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gunter that this question seems out of Stack Overflow's scope.

In more recent news, [Flutter for web](https://flutter.dev/web) is now on stable release and I suggest trying it out if you've yet to have done so. If you're eyeing to release a mobile app version of your web page as well, Flutter seems to be best fit for this use case.